# Iterative use of lambda-function in Tkinter Button

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

Using tkinter, I would like to create a graphical user interface (gui) with multiple buttons that perform an action depending on the index of the button. The problem I face is that all buttons are assigned to the last function that I define, and not the the one that I assigned iteratively to the button in the code.

Here is a simple code-example that illustrates my issue.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
r = 1
links = []
y = []
for n in range(10):
    links.append(Button(window, text='button '+str(n), cursor='hand2'))
    links[n].grid(row=r, column=3, sticky=W)
    y.append(lambda x: print('This is the Button number ' + str(n)))
    links[n].bind('<Button-1>', y[n])
    r += 1
window.mainloop()
```

Running this script opens a [gui with 10 buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2xTB.png).

Clicking on any button will print `This is the Button number 9`  (the last button). However, I would like that upon clicking button `n`, it will print `This is the Button number n` . Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: I create a list called links as my ultimate goal is to open weblinks with the buttons.

Comment: Typo error. from tkinder import * to from tkinter import *